# Python API HTTPS with Let's Encrypt certificate

Tags: python, ssl, https, gunicorn, lets-encrypt

I've got a NAS (Synology) which hosts soem of my work.
There is a mariadb database, a web server (nginx) and Docker for hosting my personal python API.

Here is a graphical view:
[image: Architecture]

As you can see, I also made a front (Vue JS) web page which uses the python API.

I want to secure all of that with HTTPS.

I successfully add a Let's Encrypt (LE) certificate and the web client use it with no problem.

But the python API is served only over HTTP, on the web client gives this error:

```
Mixed Content: The page at 'https://mydomain.fr/' was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure XMLHttpRequest endpoint 'http://mydomain:12345/myroute'. This request has been blocked; the content must be served over HTTPS.
```

And I understand it.

So I want my python API to use HTTPS.

I use a gunicorn server, and I tried several things:
Add ssl_context:

```
app.run(host='0.0.0.0', ssl_context='adhoc')
```

Add some files given by LE (I don't understand what I do):

```
CMD ["gunicorn", "--certfile=certificat.pem", "--keyfile=cleprivee.key", "--ca_certs=ca.cer", "-b", "0.0.0.0:5000", "feed:app"]
```

But I only got "Time out" with thoses tests.

Do I have to use the same certificate as the web server for the api?
How do i "give" it to the api?

Comment: It's usually a better idea to not worry about certificates in your Python program, but let a dedicated web server act as a reverse proxy in front of it. In your case, your "web station" could proxy API requests through to your Python backend, and the problem would be solved.

Comment: Good idea, thx!